# Is asking for a base theme that will allow the mimicking of a site ok?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question that will be about trying to mimicking a website. I'm just looking for to find a base theme that already has most of the features of the particular site I want to clone as close as possible to minimize the amount of theme work required. Is asking a question along these lines ok?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't just give the link to the website to mimic, the question should be fine.
Describe the features you want to implement, and add screenshots of the website you want to mimic.

For the reasons why providing just a link doesn't make the question a good question, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it